# Making Regex more safe

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to turn a bunch of regex more safe, what i mean by more safe, i want more accuracy.

So, i'm very new with RegExp, and i want know if i'm doing this right (not the Regex, but turn into more safety).

So, i'm starting now, and this is the first RegExp that i want change, i want push the 01/2011.

Past RegExp:

```
var text    = 'INSCRIÇÃO: 60.537.263/0001-66 COMP: 01/2011 COD REC: 150';
var reg     = /COMP.*?(\d\S*)/;
var match   = reg.exec(text);
console.log(match[1]);
```

New RegExp:

```
var text    = 'INSCRIÇÃO: 60.537.263/0001-66 COMP: 01/2011 COD REC: 150';
var reg     = /COMP:\s([0-9]{0,2}\/[0-9]{0,4})/;
var match   = reg.exec(text);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Why this? This text is just a part of a huge text, so i need accuraci.

Other question is about turn the Regex optional, so if doesn't match anything, return undefined.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the main question here?

Comment: About safety, i want know if the second RegExp is safety.

Comment: Please define "RegExp safety". What strings do you want to process? What are the patterns, in words at least? Look, if you always need to match digits separated with `/` straight after `COMP:`+whitespace, we can speculate about many things (make whitespace optional with `*`, avoid matching `/`+digits with `{1,4}`, etc.) I doubt this question can be answered without defined **specific** requirements.

Comment: Like i said, this text is just a part of a huge text, so i don't want push the wrong value, i want specifically push the value with two numbers, one / and four numbers, the old regex is generic, errors may occur. I want to avoid as much pull the wrong value , get it? @stribizhev

Comment: Yes, I think you need `/\bCOMP:\s*(\d{2}\/\d{4})(?!\d)/g`. `\b` is a word boundary, thus `5COMP` won't be matched, `\s*` will match 0 or more whitespace, `\d{2}` will match exactly 2 digits, `\d{4}` will match 4 digits and no more because of the look-ahead `(?!\d)` (make sure there is no digit after).

Comment: What the (?!\d) means?

Comment: See above, I updated my comment. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your feedback:

> i want specifically push the value with two numbers, one / and four numbers

You can use

```
/\bCOMP:\s*(\d{2}\/\d{4})(?!\d)/g
```

The `\b` is a word boundary, thus `5COMP` won't be matched.

The `\s*` will match 0 or more whitespace (if there must be whitespace, use `+` quantifier instead).

The `\d{2}` will match exactly 2 digits.

The `\d{4}` will match 4 digits and no more because of the look-ahead `(?!\d)`. This look-ahead just makes sure there is no digit after the 4 previous digits. You may use `\b` here as well to ensure matching a word boundary.

```js
arr = [];
var re = /\bCOMP:\s*(\d{2}\/\d{4})(?!\d)/g; 
var str = 'COMP:10/9995, COMP: 21/1234, COMP: 21/123434, REGCOMP: 21/1234';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    arr.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Perect! Thanks @stribizhev!

Comment: If i'm not asking to much, is possible make a regex optional, like.. i want that, if doesn't find, return undefined, or something like this.. so i could put || 'NOTHING' after the regex.

Comment: I updated the answer with a code snippet. Does it work as expected?